# Can't find schema for an extension point

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-wtp

I want to add an extension to my project, extensionpoint "org.eclipse.wst.xsl.ui.contentAssistProcessor", but I'm unable to load the schema. I keep getting an error message:

```
JAR entry /schema/contentAssistProcessor.exsd not found in C:\Program Files (x86)\eclipse-rcp-helios-SR1-win32\eclipse\plugins\org.eclipse.wst.xsl.ui.source_1.1.1.v201009091745.jar
```

java.io.FileNotFoundException: JAR entry /schema/contentAssistProcessor.exsd not found in C:\Program Files (x86)\eclipse-rcp-helios-SR1-win32\eclipse\plugins\org.eclipse.wst.xsl.ui.source_1.1.1.v201009091745.jar
    at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarURLConnection.connect(JarURLConnection.java:122)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarURLConnection.getInputStream(JarURLConnection.java:132)
    at java.net.URL.openStream(URL.java:1010)
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.core.util.SchemaUtil.getInputStream(SchemaUtil.java:40)
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.core.util.SchemaUtil.parseURL(SchemaUtil.java:46)
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.ui.wizards.extension.PointSelectionPage.handlePointSelection(PointSelectionPage.java:524)
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.ui.wizards.extension.PointSelectionPage.selectionChanged(PointSelectionPage.java:489)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.Viewer$2.run(Viewer.java:162)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
(snip)

If I want to see the extension point description I get a page showing:

```
Identifier: null.null

Description: 

Configuration Markup:
```

The plugin has been added to my dependencies (done automatically by eclipse) and is added to my project build path.

The plugin has been installed from the update site http://download.eclipse.org/webtools/repository/helios/, latest version 3.2.2

When I look at my plugins directory, I can see both "org.eclipse.wst.xsl.ui.source_1.1.1.v201009091745.jar" and "org.eclipse.wst.xsl.ui_1.1.1.v201009091745.jar"

Unzipping them shows nothing wrong, the schema is there and looks ok.

The error message I'm getting is the same as in the [this Eclipse bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=214923) which the submitter says is due to:

*Actually, the underlying issue is that the org.eclipse.equinox.registry plug-in
does not export the schema folder to the source bundle. I'll file a bug for
them.*

I've tried to uninstall the webtools plugins and reinstalling them with no result.

Edit: I have manually started and diagnosed the wst.xsl.ui plugin throught the plugin registry without and problems, so there doesnt seem to be a dependency issue.

I'm running out of things to try...

Answer (score 3):

I'd recommend importing the wst.ui bundle into your workspace as a source project.  You can do this through: File -> Import... -> Plugins and Fragments.  Select the org.eclipse.wst.xsl.ui and choose project with source folders.  The `schema` directory should be imported along with it, but if it's not, you may need to manually import it (ie- copy and paste from the zip file).

This will ensure that the `exsd` is available.